# При выделении грамматической основы надо включать в неё частицу "не"?

Tags: синтаксис

При выделении грамматической основы надо включать в неё частицу "не"?

Предложение:

```
Но я же не стал подлецом.
```

Я написал:

```
Я стал подлецом...
```

Comment: Надо, у вас ошибка.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Частица НЕ включается в сказуемое, например: 
Ласточек мы **не обижаем**, гнезд их **не трогаем** (из учебного пособия для 5- 9 классов "Все виды грамматического разбора" (2013 год).

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как там по школьной методике, но без "НЕ" никак не получается сохранить даже смысл. 
Здесь сказуемое - "не стал (подлецом)". "Не" - необходимая его часть.